# Notepad++ Gurus: How do I see the full line in Find results window?

Tags: notepad++

I need to extract some specific lines from a very long log file.  I have typically done this in Notepad++ by doing a search then copying the Find results window.  Unfortunately, in this case, the lines I am interested in are VERY long (3743 characters) and notepad++ is truncating them to 1025 char in the Find results window.

I suspect I could do this with a complex regex that deletes the lines I don't want; but, that is going to take a lot of work to get right.

Is there a way to increase the Find results line length?

Comment: I was able to to it with Notepad++ RegEx but it was painful and slow

Comment: I'm afraid there're no settings for this. You may have more chances asking at [Notepad++ community](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/)

Comment: What about using the "Mark" option in the find dialog and select "Bookmark line".
After clicking "Mark All", goto "Search" - "Bookmark" Choose "Remove unmarked lines"

Comment: @Toto Added [question](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/18028/how-do-i-see-the-full-line-in-find-results-window) on [Notepad ++ community](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community).  I will let you know what they say.

Comment: @markshancock – your question got interesting replies but maybe you just should do what HelpingHand [suggests](https://superuser.com/questions/1465931/notepad-gurus-how-do-i-see-the-full-line-in-find-results-window#comment2210713_1465931) instead of expecting that all corner cases of use (here: extreme line length) will be covered.

Comment: @miroxlav I already worked around the issue with e complex RegEx (and posted that) before HelpingHand responded; so, there was no real incentive to use his workaround.  Neither of these answers the original question.

Comment: @Toto could have the correct answer; but that was not provided as an Answer - it might be just a guess since he provides no explanation/reference.